# How would this snippet be rewritten using F#?

Tags: .net, ruby, f#

I'm learning F#, and I'd like to know how a snippet like this could be written using F# only:

```
2.times {
  puts "hello"
}
```

If you can explain how/if functions that take blocks are possible in F#, that would be great as well.

Comment: @Geo: F# has very different idioms, don't try to express things the same way you do them in Ruby.

Comment: @Mauricio: there's nothing particularly idiomatic about writing "hello" two times, though.

Comment: @Dmitri: Geo commented "not quite Ruby, but it will do" to Rahul's answer. Therefore my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times function can be written as :

```
let times act n =
    for i in 1 .. n do
        act()
```

and can be invoked as :

```
2 |> times (fun () -> printfn "Hello")
```

Comment: I think he's looking for lambda usage, I'd put the printf as a lambda

Comment: @Scheffer : Edited as per your suggestion. Thanks! :)

Comment: minor typo: printfln -> printfn

Comment: 2 |> times (fun _ -> printfn "Hello")

Comment: by the way, is it possible for that lambda to have more than one line? In Ruby I have braces to delimit it's body.

Comment: I downvoted now because the answer is wrong.  Earlier I edited to fix, but you reverted that, and also have added a new, also-wrong answer.  The new code does not even compile; the old code does the wrong thing.

Comment: @Geo : Brian has answered your question in this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814278/how-to-do-multiline-lambda-expressions-in-f

Answer (score 11):

Here's one that uses a lambda (basically a ruby block):

```
{1..2} |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> printfn "hello")
```

Here the `Seq.iter` function is taking a lambda as parameter, which is executed in each iteration.

Comment: what does the `_` in the lambda stand for?

Comment: It is a wildcard. The _ will match any value and is a way
of telling the compiler that you’re not interested in using this value.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a compiler handy, so someone please fix this up if it doesn't compile.  Here's a way to define the corresponding F# extension member.

```
type System.Int32 with
    member this.Times(act) =
        for i in 1..this do
            act()

(2).Times (fun() -> printfn "Hello")
```